# Is it acceptable to use `grep` to check for the presence of a string in a file within an init script?

Tags: linux, service, init.d, init

Is it okay for me to check the contents of a file for a given string with `grep` in an `init` script?

I am concerned about introducing dependencies and general convention when it comes `init` scripts, and if running `grep` or other tools violates some credo.

Comment: supposedly you're supposed to use $() versus \`backticks\` now, but other than that I think you're good.  Then again, backticks are more universal though ?deprecated?. Even the most stripped down versions of linux and linuxy OSs have grep.

Comment: When I can do $(string expansion) on stackexchange, then I'll stop using `backticks`. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iniscripts can do whatever they want. Of course it makes sense not to introduce new dependencies, just for the initscripts. grep however is fine on pretty much any system that's posix/susv3 compatible (linux, bsd, solaris, other derivatives).

For more utilities that should always be there, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/idx/utilities.html

Comment: Surprised that `which` isn't on there, but I guess that can be done in in with a shell one-liner.

Comment: You can use `type` instead of which. The functionality is slightly different, but you can get equivalent results.

Answer (score 1):

In short, YES. So long as the file you are looking for is mounted at that point.

Comment: I wasn't really asking if it was _possible_, but I will in fact handle this condition as well, so thanks.

Comment: It IS acceptable and you will find that many of the init scripts do this.